# Error in Visual Studio Code With JS, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with compiling in Visual Studio with JavaScript.
In line 11, where there is `datos.innerHTML`,

```
alert("Hola Mundo");


var nombre = "Juan";
var altura = 180;
var concatenacion = nombre + " " + altura;
/*document.write(nombre);
document.write(altura);*/
/*document.write(concatenacion);*/
var datos = document.getElementById("datos");
datos.innerHTML = '

    <h1>Soy la caja de datos</h1>
    <h2>Mi nombres es: $(nombre)</h2>
    <h3>Altura: $(altura)</h3>
';
```

there is a problem with the compilation. Does not accept labels `h1, h2, h3`. Should I install an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, single/double quoted strings are always single line(without line continuations). To fix it, use a multiline string(aka template strings) by using backticks instead:

```
datos.innerHTML = `
    <h1>Soy la caja de datos</h1>
    <h2>Mi nombres es: $(nombre)</h2>
    <h3>Altura: $(altura)</h3>
`;
```

Edit: see Ari Firmanto's answer about using ${}.

Answer (score 2):

the other answer is correct, but you need to wrap with ${} for variable in order to used with ` (backticks)

```
  datos.innerHTML = `
        <h1>Soy la caja de datos</h1>
        <h2>Mi nombres es: (${nombre})</h2>
        <h3>Altura: (${altura})</h3>
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes in that statement need to be backticks/grave marks ` rather than ':

```
datos.innerHTML = `

    <h1>Soy la caja de datos</h1>
    <h2>Mi nombres es: $(nombre)</h2>
    <h3>Altura: $(altura)</h3>
`;
```

Regular single and double quotes are for regular strings in JavaScript; template strings and multiline strings use the backtick character.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have line breaks in the string.

**Option 1**

Keep the html string within quotes but concat the varialbles using `+` operator

```
datos.innerHTML = '<h1>Soy la caja de datos</h1><h2>Mi nombres es: ' 
                   + nombre + 
                   '</h2><h3>Altura: ' 
                   + altura + '</h3>';
```

**Option 2**

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and give variables like `${variable-name}`. Check the support for Internet explorer if you are using this method.

```
datos.innerHTML = `
    <h1>Soy la caja de datos</h1>
    <h2>Mi nombres es: ${nombre}</h2>
    <h3>Altura: ${altura}</h3>
`;
```